# How to get Cell Index on TextField Delegate Method in TableViewCell Class

Tags: uitableview, swift3

Please review the code below. I want to get cell index when textfield should begin editing.

```
class SingleLineText: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

 func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        let cell: SingleLineText = textField.superview!.superview as! SingleLineText
        let table: UITableView = cell.superview as! UITableView
        let textFieldIndexPath = table.indexPath(for: cell)
        print(textFieldIndexPath as Any)

        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: What seems to be the issue?

Comment: crash on this line         let cell: SingleLineText = textField.superview!.superview as! SingleLineText

Comment: Do not force unwrap optionals. Also show your `SingleLineText` full code. Or atleast the code that shows view heirarchy.

Answer (score 0):

In cellForRowAt method just add:

```
youCell.textField.tag = indexPath.row
```

and use it Like:

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

        let indexPath: IndexPath = IndexPath(row: textField.tag, section: 0)
        //here is your indexPath

        return true
    }
}
```